# Having trouble figuring out a ruby math error. advice?

Tags: ruby

Multiplication is the only operator that works. every other operator

still multiplies for some reason. for example, 5+5=25, 6-2=12, 6/2=12.

It looks as though all my operators are correct in the code, so I am

not quite sure why this is happening.

```
puts "Enter your first Number: "
first_num = gets.to_i

puts "Enter your modifier"
modifier = gets

puts "Enter second number"
second_num = gets.to_i

def add(first_num, second_num)
  return first_num + second_num
end

def subtract(first_num, second_num)
  return first_num - second_num
end

def multiply(first_num, second_num)
  return first_num * second_num
end

def divide(first_num, second_num)
  return first_num / second_num
end

case modifier
when +
  final_num = add(first_num, second_num)
when -
  final_num = subtract(first_num, second_num)
when *
  final_num = multiply(first_num, second_num)
when %
  final_num = divide(first_num, second_num)
end

puts final_num
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gets` returns strings. More specifically `gets` returns the string entered by the user *including* the line break which is appended when the user presses ENTER.

Therefore, it makes sense to first remove the new line from the user input with `gets.chomp`. And second, compare `modifier` with strings containing operators in the `case` block:

```
puts "Enter your modifier"
modifier = gets.chomp

# ...

case modifier
when '+'
  final_num = add(first_num, second_num)
when '-'
  final_num = subtract(first_num, second_num)
when '*'
  final_num = multiply(first_num, second_num)
when '%'
  final_num = divide(first_num, second_num) 
end
```

Or insted of the `case` block a refactored version using a hash and `send`:

```
OPS = { '+' => 'add', '-' => 'substract', '*' => 'multiply', '%' => 'divide' }
final_num = send(OPS[modifier], first_num, second_num)
```

Actually, I am surprised that Ruby doesn't raise a syntax error.

Comment: `final_num = case ...`?

Comment: Hi @AlekseiMatiushkin, you are right, missed that in my second version. I the first version I do not want to make that change to not confuse the OP, but removing that duplication would be good too.

Comment: Don't forget to `chomp` the input.

Comment: Regarding the syntax: Ruby sees empty `when`'s followed by `+(final_num=…)`, `-(final_num=…)`, `*(final_num=…)` and `%(final_num=…)`, i.e. unary plus, unary minus, splat, and percent string.

Answer (score 0):

Put `" "` around your `operators` in your case statements.So case modifier when `"+"` etc .gets saves things as a `string`, so your modifier is saved as a `string`.